# Loading a form from a form include file in a module

Tags: 7, forms

I have an external form that needs to be loaded inside a template file, used by a block. Right now, i'm a bit confused as to how to load this .inc. Looking at the API docs point to [module_load_include()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) which I've tried with no luck (see example 1, from the template file):

```
module_load_include('inc', 'example2'); 
print(render(drupal_get_form("example2_form"))); //Form method in inc file is called "example2_form();
```

The actual form method is just a few settings for now, once I prove this works...

```
function example2_form($form, $form_state) {
  $form['fname'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    "#attributes" => array(
      'placeholder' => t("First Name"),
    ),
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = "example2_form_validate";
  $form['#submit'][] = "example2_form_submit";

  return $form;
}
```

I figure the cleanest approach (besides figuring out what could cause the .inc to not load here) is to just drop the form code into the .module, and load the Form array in the blocks `hook_block_view().` However, I like to keep stuff clean, so if there's something I'm overlooking here, or how to best do this, it would be cool to know.

File name for the form include is *example2.form.inc*.

Comment: Just for clarification:1) what is your module name? In your `module_load_include()` sample, you give it as `example2_form`, but in your form method you show has the same name...these can't both be right. 2) Is your function ever called by other code? Generally, you need to call a function returning a form from somewhere else, like e.g. `hook_menu()` etc.

Comment: Whoops. Didn't catch that. I've updated that to reference the module, _example2_.

Answer (score 0):

Module_load_include includes the file with extension and filename. Sinds your file is called example2.form.inc and you include the file example2.inc, it doesn't work.

You should be using

```
Module_load_include('inc', 'example2.form');
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/module_load_include/7.x) is

```
module_load_include('suffix', 'module', 'file_without_suffix');
```

Files can be loaded in module.info via the files[] array but this should be for classes or interface files. [enter link description here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/writing-module-info-files-drupal-7x#files)

If you want to load a form into a template manually, then yes define the block and hook_block_view($delta) will need to load the form include file.